# Cross Join taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBX_RRDGenieDeletedItem](
    [DeletedId] [decimal](25, 0) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO TBX_RRDGenieDeletedItem values (90309955000010401948421)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbNicheCIS](
    [OccurrenceID] [decimal](25, 0) NULL,
    [OccurrenceFileNo] [varchar](20) NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbNicheCIS values (90309955000010401948421,'3212')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Asset_Table](
    [user_crimenumber] [varchar](4000) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Asset_Table VALUES ('3212; 4512; 34322; 45674; 33221')
```

The only table I designed was dbNicheCIS.  I am trying to find all of the rows in tbx_rrdgeniedeleteditem that are also in `Asset_Table` using the `LIKE` statement.  `Asset_Table` contains the `OccurrenceFileNo` (note that asset table contains occurrencefileno: 3212, which relates to `OccurrenceID: 90309955000010401948421)`.  I have tried this:

```
Select user_crimenumber from tbx_rrdgeniedeleteditem --asset_table.user_crimenumber 
inner join dbNicheCIS on tbx_rrdgeniedeleteditem.deletedid = dbNicheCIS.OccurrenceID
cross join asset_table
where deletedid like '903%' and asset_table.user_crimenumber like '%' + occurrencefileno + '%'
```

It works, but it takes hours to run.  Is there a better way to approach it rather than a cross join?

Comment: why not use inner join

Comment: Joins on decimal column is always a headache. :(

Comment: @Dudi Konfino, AssetTable contains millions on rows.  It is too slow.

Comment: maybe partition may help here?

Comment: You might find an approach that runs, "a bit faster" than what you have.  But I doubt you will find an "efficient" approach.  Perhaps you can bring this to your supervisor as a use-case to properly normalize the tables?  You could have an efficient query if Asset_Table were properly normalized.   (If disk space is not a concern, maybe create a new reporting table that builds nightly and is a normalized version of Asset_Table?)

Comment: @Deadzone, I was thinking of a nightly scheduled task. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN and also you can eliminate LIKE for the number comparison like below

```
Select user_crimenumber from tbx_rrdgeniedeleteditem
inner join dbNicheCIS 
on tbx_rrdgeniedeleteditem.deletedid = dbNicheCIS.OccurrenceID
inner join asset_table
on CAST(LEFT([DeletedId], 3) AS [decimal](25, 0)) =903 
and asset_table.user_crimenumber like '%' + occurrencefileno + '%'
```

Comment: This looks promising. I will try it shortly and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid this will not help too much. This query produces identical execution plan as the OP's query. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670980/performance-of-inner-join-compared-to-cross-join

Comment: It is too slow.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @w0051977, index won't either help as you are having % in the front too. better to create a seperate table for comma seperated values like assocatin table.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of the in operator in this case

```
SELECT * FROM TBX_RRDGenieDeletedItem
WHERE DeletedId IN (
SELECT DISTINCT OccurrenceID FROM dbNicheCIS
INNER JOIN Split(...) ON ...)
```

Updated: You can create a custom split function which will split the values into a temp table and then do the join.

Comment: Please reread the question. Usercrimenumber contains delimited values. This will not work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @w0051977 updated, you can create a custom split function to deal with this case

Answer (score 0):

You need to index your tables to get faster query response.

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_dbNicheCIS_OccurrenceID] ON [dbNicheCIS]
([OccurrenceID] ASC, [OccurrenceFileNo] ASC)

CREATE INDEX [IX_TBX_RRDGenieDeletedItem_DeletedId] ON [dbo].[TBX_RRDGenieDeletedItem]
([DeletedId] ASC)
```

Creating such indexes replaces "Table scan" in query execution plan with faster "Index scan" and "Index seek". But you cannot solve `like '%' + occurrencefileno + '%'` problem with simple indexes.
There you will have to use [full text indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). After you define fulltext index on `asset_table.user_crimenumber`, you can use following query

```
SELECT user_crimenumber 
FROM tbx_rrdgeniedeleteditem  di --asset_table.user_crimenumber 
JOIN dbNicheCIS dnc
ON di.deletedid = dnc.OccurrenceID
CROSS JOIN asset_table at
WHERE di.deletedid like '903%' 
AND CONTAINS(at.user_crimenumber, occurrencefileno)
```

But it is a bad practice to store your `occurrencefileno` list as a varchar value delimited with semicolons. If you were the author of this database design, you should have tried to normalize the data, so that you got one row for every `occurrencefileno` and not a string like `'3212; 4512; 34322; 45674; 33221'`.

You can also create as a first step before querying a normalized version of `asset_table.user_crimenumber` and then use this table with normal indexes as a base for your further queries.

To split your `asset_table.user_crimenumber` fields you can [use the Fn_Split() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496058.aspx) as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226276/how-to-use-result-of-an-sql-select-statement-in-dbo-fnsplit-function-as-input).

---

There is also option using the `fnSplit` to rewrite your query this way:

```
SELECT user_crimenumber 
FROM tbx_rrdgeniedeleteditem  di --asset_table.user_crimenumber 
JOIN dbNicheCIS dnc
ON di.deletedid = dnc.OccurrenceID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT at.user_crimenumber, f.item FROM asset_table at 
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplit(at.user_crimenumber,';') f   ) at
ON at.item=dnc.occurrencefileno
WHERE di.deletedid like '903%'
```

If you create `fnSplit` as CLR in C# as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721270%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) you may get even faster results. But it will not speed up your query magically.