# Check if list is empty or null then check SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query like this,

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.id, t.name, t.randomid, trand.name as randomname
from t left join
     t trand
     on t.randomid = trand.id
where t.id in (select item from dbo.ufnSplit(@ids,','));
```

[Here is code for ufnSplit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226276/how-to-use-result-of-an-sql-select-statement-in-dbo-fnsplit-function-as-input)

How can I add check so that if `@ids` is null or empty  only then use `where` condition, I want this condition only if @ids is not null or empty ?

```
where t.id in (select item from dbo.ufnSplit(@ids,','));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will check if @ids is null or empty, and then check the where clause.

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.id, t.name, t.randomid, trand.name as randomname
from t left join
     t trand
     on t.randomid = trand.id
where @ids = '' 
   or @ids is null
   or t.id in (select item from dbo.ufnSplit(@ids,','))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Where` clause

```
where t.id in (select item from dbo.ufnSplit(@ids,',')) or nullif(@ids,'') is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a conditional `WHERE` clause like so:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.id, t.name, t.randomid, trand.name as randomname
from t left join
     t trand
     on t.randomid = trand.id
where @ids IS NULL OR t.id IN (select item from dbo.ufnSplit(@ids,','));
```

So if it's `NULL` it will return everything, otherwise it will evaluate the `OR` part of the `WHERE` clause.

You may need to edit the function: `dbo.ufnSplit` to handle `NULL` input gracefully for this to work.